# Trouble with regex matching last part

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex:

```
solo_LL01_[\p{Alnum}|-]+_\d{10}_V\d{4}(1[0-2]|0[1-9])(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])(2[0-3]|[01][0-9])([0-5][0-9])(I|C)?(_firsttest)?\.fits$
```

Matched against:

```
solo_LL01_eui-fsi-174_0715246200_V201607271145C_firsttest.fits
```

I would like to make the firsttest text any numbers/characters. I tried some variations such as:

```
solo_LL01_[\p{Alnum}|-]+_\d{10}_V\d{4}(1[0-2]|0[1-9])(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])(2[0-3]|[01][0-9])([0-5][0-9])(I|C)?(_[\p{Alnum}_])?\.fits$
```

But just seem to get it to work.
Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation of [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), especially the parts about "Predefined character classes" :

> \w    A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]

and "Quantifiers":

> X*  :  X, zero or more times
>
> X+  :  X, one or more times

The following should match any number of charatcter / numbers :-

```
[\w]*
```

For one or more Characters or Numbers :-

```
[\w]+
```

In fact what you tried is also correct, except that you missed the quantifier * (any number of matches) or + (1 or more matches) ... so your regex just needs to be :-

```
solo_LL01_[\p{Alnum}|-]+_\d{10}_V\d{4}(1[0-2]|0[1-9])(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])(2[0-3]|[01][0-9])([0-5][0-9])(I|C)?(_[\p{Alnum}_]*)?\.fits$
```

or

```
solo_LL01_[\p{Alnum}|-]+_\d{10}_V\d{4}(1[0-2]|0[1-9])(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])(2[0-3]|[01][0-9])([0-5][0-9])(I|C)?(_[\p{Alnum}_]+)?\.fits$
```

Depending on which Quantifier (* or +) you wish to use

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `[A-Za-z0-9]+`?

```
solo_LL01_[\p{Alnum}|-]+_\d{10}_V\d{4}(1[0-2]|0[1-9])(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])(2[0-3]|[01][0-9])([0-5][0-9])(I|C)?_([A-Za-z0-9]+)?\.fits$
```